# wpf app starts from debugger but not standalone .exe

Tags: wpf

Pretty simple WPF app, both Debug and Release builds run when started from debugger.
When I try to start one of the .exes from the command line, it crashes.
In the xml file generated to send to MS, I found this:
    `<ProblemSignatures>
        <EventType>APPCRASH</EventType>
        <Parameter0>App.exe</Parameter0>
        <Parameter1>0.2.0.0</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>5260abb5</Parameter2>
        <Parameter3>KERNELBASE.dll</Parameter3>
        <Parameter4>6.1.7601.18229</Parameter4>
        <Parameter5>51fb1677</Parameter5>
        <Parameter6>e0434352</Parameter6>
        <Parameter7>000000000000940d</Parameter7>
    </ProblemSignatures>`
I have added a handler to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, but it doesn't appear to be catching anything.
I'd appreciate any ideas on what may be going wrong...  Improperly handling resources such as some .png files the app uses?
An issue with reading values from the registry?

TIA --

Comment: What if you run the app as Admin, are you reading/writing files to restricted locations (outside of ProgramData/UsaerData)

Comment: No joy trying to run as admin.  No file i/o, just reading/writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER (but that doesn't happen at startup).

Comment: Have a look at the Windows EventViewer, you may be able to get a stacktrace from there.

Comment: Interesting -- the .exe runs when started from `\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Release`, but not `\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Release`.  Seems like something is not getting packaged properly...  I'll have a look at the EventViewer, thanks for the replies.

Comment: From Event Viewer:  `Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at MyApp.App.Main()`
When I try to trap that exception when starting from the debugger, it never catches it.

Comment: Are there project references that are being copied to the output directory (bin\release) but not (obj\release)?

Comment: The problem seems to be `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll`.  If I copy that to the dir with MyApp.exe, the app runs as expected.  I have another WPF app that uses Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll, but I can't figure out what the difference in config is...

Comment: Try attaching to the app, and debugging it there with all exceptions turned on. ( Debug-->Exceptions... then click on all the checkboxes.)

Answer (score 0):

When you say that your `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event handler doesn't catch anything, were you talking about when you were debugging? If so, then that's fine... add some code into that handler that will save details of the `Exception` (and any inner `Exception`s) into a text file. Now build a new Release version and run it. This way, you should at least get details of the problem.

If for any reason that doesn't work, then your problem must be somewhere either in the `MainWindow.cs` constructor, or in code that is called from the constructor, or any code that the WPF Framework may be calling at start up. Therefore, if you look through the start up code carefully, you may be able to identify any lines of code that could potentially cause problems.

Examples of this are any code that accesses resources, particularly databases and network drives, or anything else that might be offline or that a user might not have access to. When you have detected these lines of code, simply add a load of calls to `MessageBox.Show` to show you what the current values are:

```
MessageBox.Show("Debugging", string.Format("Model: ", Model.ToString()));
MessageBox.Show("Debugging", string.Format("User: ", User.ToString()));
MessageBox.Show("Debugging", string.Format("User.Security: ", User.Security.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm pretty sure the issue is `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll` ; when I copy that to where the .exe is started from, the app works as expected.